# Easy way to extract json object properties into an array?

Tags: javascript, json

Given the following JSON object, is there an easy way to extract just the values of the `results` object properties?

```
var j={"success":true,
       "msg":["Clutch successfully updated."],
       "results":{"count_id":2,
                  "count_type":"Clutch",
                  "count_date":"2000-01-01",
                  "fish_count":250,
                  "count_notes":"test"}
      };

var arr= doSomething(j.results);
//arr=[2, "Clutch","2000-01-01",250,"test"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function would be something like

```
var doSomething = function (obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var x in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        arr.push(obj[x]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function resultstoArray (resultsData) {
  var myArray = new Array();
  for (var key in resultsData) {
    myArray.push(resultsData[key]);
  }
  return myArray;
}

var arr = resultsToArray(j.results);
```